# Databinding with AppCompatEditText does not work in Release build

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following view which where the content of the AppCompatEditText should bind to the "ArticleName" property of the ViewModel. This works fine in debug builds but not in Release builds. What's the reason for this effect? It's a pretty basic ViewModel of a dialog.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeadline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle"
        android:text="New item" />
    <AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editArticleName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtHeadline"
        local:MvxBind="Text ArticleName" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_below="@id/editArticleName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        local:MvxBind="Click AddItem;Enabled CanAddItem"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private string m_ArticleName;

        public string ArticleName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ArticleName;
            }

            set
            {
                m_ArticleName = value;
                RaiseAllPropertiesChanged();

                // this setter is never called
            }
        }

        public MvxCommand AddItem
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public bool CanAddItem
        {
            get
            {
                return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_ArticleName);
            }
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            AddItem = new MvxCommand(doAddItem);
        }

        private void doAddItem()
        {
           // is never called in releases build because CanAddItem is never true
        }
    }
```

I also added the following statement to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs with no effect:

```
    public void Include(AppCompatEditText text)
    {
        text.TextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
        text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
        text.Text = "Test";
    }
```

Edit:

The same effect occurs if I swap the AppCompatEditText with a regular EditText.

Comment: if something work in debug version and not working in release mode do check proguard.

Comment: Proguard is not active (never changed this setting though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MvvmCross the event for text binding has changed to use `AfterTextChanged`.

So you can make the following change in your `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs`

`text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;`